# Network Disabled

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have just installed ubuntu server edition in order to create a home network. But I am not able to find IP of the machine through ifconfig (showing only localhost). Then I tried

```
 lspci | grep -i ethernet
```

output:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

lshw -C Network

Then output was `*-network DISABLED`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to list ip address associated with an interface was `ifconfig`,

To activate an interface, use `ifconfig XXX up`, otherwise it would shown as `DISABLED`

Comment: `ifconfig` has been replaced with `ip`

Comment: @LondonRob Nope, it's just not installed by default on CentOS

Comment: Sorry! Should've added my citation. I was quoting from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145449/78809).