# ifconfig command not found

Tags: centos, networking, command, ifconfig

I've just installed CentOS7 as a virtual machine on my mac (osx10.9.3 + virtualbox) .Running `ifconfig` returns command not found. Also running `sudo /sbin/ifconfig` returns commmand not found. I am root. The output of
`echo $PATH` is as below.

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/robbert/.local/bin:/home/robbert/bin
```

Is my path normal? If not, how can I change it?

Also, I don't have an internet connection on virtual machine yet, maybe that's a factor.

Comment: Try `sudo /sbin/ifconfig`.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `/sbin/ifconfig`? Looking at my system, I can't find an `/sbin/config` either. BTW, what do you get from `ls /sbin/ifconfig`?

Comment: Thank you, I tried, it returns command not found. I guess the net-tools package is absent. I'll try to fix my internet connection first to download net-tools.

Comment: Yes, I meant /sbin/ifconfig. ls /sbin/ifconfig doesn't exist so I'll have to install that. I guess that's it. I think it's very weird that it didn't install by default.

Comment: It isn't installed by default probably because it is regarded as obsolete: it is replaced by `ip`.

Comment: what `locate ifconfig` says

Comment: Try `ip` command. ifconfig is deprecated now

Comment: @Ramesh No need for `sudo`: `/sbin/ifconfig` is enough if you want to see settings. You only need `sudo` if you want to change settings (and then `sudo ifconfig` is enough).

Comment: @SHW Just because the author of the `ip` tool has decided that `ifconfig` was deprecated doesn't mean that the rest of the world has to stop using it.

Comment: I was under impression that Linux community had deprecated `ifconfig`. Anyway, thanks for enlightening :)

Answer (score 328, accepted):

**TL/DR:** `ifconfig` is now `ip a`. Try `ip -s -c -h a`.

Your path looks OK, but does not include `/sbin`, which may be intended.

You were probably looking for the command `/sbin/ifconfig`.

If this file does not exist (try `ls /sbin/ifconfig`), the command may just be not installed.

It is part of the package `net-tools`,
 which is not installed by default, because it's **deprecated**
and **superseded** by the command
 **`ip`** from the package **`iproute2`**.

The function of `ifconfig` without options is replaced by `ip` specifying the *object* `address`.

```
ifconfig
```

is equivalent to

```
ip addr show
```

and, because the *object* argument can be abbreviated and *command* defaults to `show`, also to

```
ip a
```

The output format is somewhat different:

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:9258474 (9.2 MB)  TX bytes:9258474 (9.2 MB)
[ ... ]
```

and

```
$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[ ... ]
```

Note the output is more terse:
It does not show counts of packets handled in normal or other ways.

For that, add the option `-s` (`-stats`, `-statistics`):

```
$ ip -s addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    74423      703      0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    74423      703      0       0       0       0
```

But what you actually want to see may be this:

```
$ ip -stats -color -human addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    74.3k      700      0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    74.3k      700      0       0       0       0
```

It shows counts with suffixes like `26.1M` or `79.3k` and colors some relevant terms and addresses.

**If you feel the command is too long, use the short options:**
This is equivalent:

```
ip -s -c -h a
```

Comment: +1 for `ip`. `net-tools` has been deprecated in favor of `iproute2`.

Comment: @Kiwy Oh, I would'nt mind if you'd add some details of that debate (but leave out some body related details), I actually never used it myself. Somebody could even file a bug report on the problems you see, then?

Comment: As [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236744/20107), the equivalent `ifconfig` command is `ip addr`.

Comment: @acoder Thanks for the useful hint, I expanded the answer accordingly.

Comment: is there a ip xxx command for receiving the RX and TX packets like shown in ifconfig?

Comment: Yes - add the option `-s` (`-stats`, `-statistics`): `ip -s addr`

Comment: Those colors look terrible on a dark background.

Comment: Also may be helpful **Deprecated Linux networking commands and their replacements**: https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/

Comment: Is deprecated because is ifconfig? They dont like the name? (yes i understand the point about functionality, but this is not a good reason to just remove the command)  Why they dont just keep the command for compatibility with scripts in servers, for example creating a alias? Linux is starting to lost the point..., and more crap there are being done with linux, how systemd can be useful in a simple unix-like server? better migrate to freebsd before is too late? For example is practically impossible in a easy way to change the ip of some distros without restarting in text mode today!

Comment: My case is that after doing `yum update` and `yum upgrade`, the `net-tools` is removed. I think it is because it's deprecated. Reinstall it solves the problem.

Comment: @MatejJ With "external" you mean "from the public internet" I asssume. This address is most probably managed by your router, by using NAT. That means the external address is the address of the router. The router forwards specific connections to your computer, which has a local address. So what seems to be the external address of your computer is actually not an address of your computer at all. Your computer does not even know that it has one. It could have multiple, too.

Comment: Sorry i meant ip address which is visible in lan network..

Answer (score 44):

(verified) The default minimal install of CENTOS 7 does not install net-tools.

(verified) 'ifconfig' command will become available on installing package net-tools

-How to install net-tools through yum for the not so linux experts.

1) have a root privilege shell or be on the sudo list.

2a) At a root shell prompt (#)

```
yum install net-tools
```

2b) User account on the sudo list

```
sudo yum install net-tools
```

If the package is installed it will state so and exit yum. (Then it sounds like a path issue). 
If not installed yum will prompt the user to continue after a few local / network package checks. The install will (should) take but a moment.. presto ifconfig is now installed.

If you feel adventurous..
The equivalent of using `ifconfig` in displaying the interface / address information using ip

```
ip addr
```

Comment: perfect answer...worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Since everyone else has already provided the answer to finding ifconfig or available alternatives, I will provide some generic tips on how to get out of this situation because this is not the first or last time one would need to get hold of a command/package/utility on their system (basically I am teaching a person how to fish :). The instructions are for RHEL/CentOS.

Scenario 1: If that command already exists on another system:

1. `which ifconfig` <- find the location of ifconfig. It might say /usr/sbin/ifconfig
2. `rpm -qf /usr/sbin/ifconfig` <- This will give you the name of the rpm (like net-tools-2.0.0)
3. `sudo yum install net-tools` <- Run this on your system to install the package.

Scenario 2: If you don't have another reference system, run the command `yum whatprovides ifconfig`. This will tell you the package name that contains the command and, if it already exists on your system, the path of the command. If the package doesn't exist, you just need to run sudo yum install  to install it and you should be on your way.

These are generic instructions to find and install any package. I am not going into details about repos/other distros and other stuff here, so that you can get started.

HTH.