# Command route not found

Tags: debian, route

I can' t use the command `route`:

```
route
bash: route: command not found
```

Why  is it not found? (I'm using debian 9).

I tried to run it as root but it still does not work. However it is supposed to work also without root.

Additional diagnostics:

```
whereis route
route:
```

`which route` (empty output).

`export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` (no output) and nothing changes.

I already have `iproute2` installed, to be sure I ran:
`apt --reinstall install iproute2`

Comment: Do you see it if you do `sudo -i` instead?

Comment: The fact that you have two very different answers already is indicating that this question is far too broad.  This amounts to an "It doesn't work!" question, and such questions are poor.  Really, people cannot tell why things are happening as they are without pertinent information about what your account is, what your `PATH` is, and why you think that you even have a `route` command in the first place on a package-based operating system.  None of that is in the question as it stands.

Comment: I ran it as root

Comment: If you want more info ask me i don't know what add. The second answer is good and tell me to check a required package of that command. And this command is supposed to works with normal user.

Comment: It seems you already have already a couple of poor quality questions due to (ab)use root use. Have people not advised you it is poor practice to run a system as root by default?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Which questions are due to root?

Comment: @GAD3R was that update the answer, thanks.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro tell me why this question is poor, why the the other questions are poor (and which) and WHY root use is related!!!

Comment: I am not your maid or employee, beware the imperative. thanks.

Comment: `/sbin/` is not always in path for normal user, but is for `root`.  If you'd shown the value of your `$PATH` variable, that would have avoided the irrelevant answers.

Comment: @JdeBP only 1 answer,  and if i knew about that i would add it in the question. I 'm not familiar with `/sbin/`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro why is root related?

Comment: @JdeBP here there is a similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145447/ifconfig-command-not-found  118 + and 41 stars...

Comment: Notice that the differences from that to yours are the very ones that I mentioned.  That question gave people the value of `PATH` and what user account was being used right from the start, in the question.

Comment: run it as `/sbin/route`

Comment: -1 as this question is very hard to understand. Please proof-read and edit, to make it easy to read, and to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor after I posted the question people ask me more info, now the question is as the original.

Comment: @Scorpion  removing stuff did not help. I have re-written as best I can. I have improved the grammar and clarity (Hope it is correct). I appreciate that English may not be your first language, so in future avoid using abbreviation. Also proof-read your text, then edit, to ensure that it makes sense.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor all the stuffs is pointless the problem was the missing package . Which abbreviation?

Comment: “I can' t to use the” and “Why it isn't found?”

Comment: The extra info that i added to the original question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The "command not found" error means you don't have the command installed.

Using [Debian's "search the contents of packages"](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=route) page brings up:

```
...
/sbin/route     net-tools [not powerpc]
....
```

So (providing your CPU isn't PowerPC) you should install the `net-tools` package.

Comment: How can this answer be correct, when root can run the command?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The OP wasn't very clear -- by "I ran it as root", I believe they meant "I entered `route` as root, and still got the same error", not "it runs when I try it as root".

Comment: @JigglyNaga "I ran it as as root" means I ran `route` as a root user, pretty simple. Because one told me to run it as root (sudo -i).

Answer (score 14):

You need install package net-tools.

Answer (score 7):

The `/sbin` isn't in your PATH, use:

```
$ /sbin/route
```

or :

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
$ route
```

You can add the above command to your `.bashrc`:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/sbin" >> .bashrc
source .bashrc
```

The `net-tools` provide the `route` command. Reading the output of `route` command doesn't require a special right.

Comment: How can i check? If i use `/sbin/route` i get:
`bash: /sbin/route: No such file or directory`.

Comment: And also `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` didn't work.

Comment: First nothing, second `route:`

Comment: Are you using the same machine, for all your your tests?: First it is installed, then it is not, then it is already installed, then not.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes same machine, the package already installed is another.